# How to simplify Assembly Translation Shift Right by 32 Xor Absolute Number And Value

Tags: assembly, xor, shift, absolute-value, ida

I don't know the original code but I don't believe it's this complicated with right shift's and abs.

Here is how the decompiled IDA PRO code renamed looks like

```
char Ship; //Could be 0-7 (8 is reversed for special purpose)
char NewShip = 1; //Could be 0-7  (8 is reversed for special purpose)
short Frequency = 0; //This could be from 0 to 9999
bool NumberToFrequency = true;

Frequency = GetNextFrequencyToJoin(player->MyArena);
if ( NumberToFrequency )
{ //TODO: maybe the below is just Frequency % 7; ?
  NewShip = (((unsigned long)Frequency >> 32) ^ abs(Frequency) & 7) - ((unsigned long)Frequency >> 32);
  Ship = NewShip;
} else {
  Ship = NewShip;
}
```

Here is a IDEOne test http://ideone.com/Q2bEjU

Seems `NewShip = abs(frequency) & 7);` is all I really need it seems I tested all the possibilities by looping it never screws up.

Another decompiler gave me this result

```
 asm("cdq ");
 NewShip = ((Var1 ^ Var2) - Var2 & 7 ^ Var2) - Var2;
```

Which has no right shifts or anything still looks alien to me, probably shows how absolute number works and still no clue where right shift 32's came from.

Whats the `NumberToFrequency` suppose to do is make the frequency the same as the ship but of course the frequency goes past 7 so the remaining values should still translate to Ship values so I assume it's just a modulus `%` of 7.

But why such a complicated code maybe it means something completely different? I'm just asking what the code means. I'll add the assembly code below. I can't even find the Shift right 32 in the assembly below I'm pretty sure it's in same place.

```
.text:0040DD3A                 mov     ecx, [ebp+1Ch]  ; arena
.text:0040DD3D                 call    GetNextFrequencyToJoin
.text:0040DD42                 mov     ecx, [ebp+1Ch]
.text:0040DD45                 mov     si, ax
.text:0040DD48                 mov     [esp+220h+var_20C], si
.text:0040DD4D                 cmp     [ecx+1ACCEh], ebx
.text:0040DD53                 jz      short loc_40DD98
.text:0040DD55                 movsx   eax, si
.text:0040DD58                 cdq
.text:0040DD59                 xor     eax, edx
.text:0040DD5B                 sub     eax, edx
.text:0040DD5D                 and     eax, 7
.text:0040DD60                 xor     eax, edx
.text:0040DD62                 sub     eax, edx
.text:0040DD64                 mov     [esp+220h+var_20F], al
```

EDIT:
I found the answer on my own seems those shift 32 `>> 32` are useless garbage added for some old C compiling support with types to match 32 bit DWORD's or some crap like that.

Comment: Side note: [ida] is the preferred tag ([ida] and [ida-pro] should be synonyms; see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308568/pro-ida-ida-pro)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shifts are not useless. It is a form of banchless logic that Hexray did not manage to reproduce in its c disassembly.

```
.text:0040DD55                 movsx   eax, si
.text:0040DD58                 cdq
.text:0040DD59                 xor     eax, edx
.text:0040DD5B                 sub     eax, edx
.text:0040DD5D                 and     eax, 7
.text:0040DD60                 xor     eax, edx
.text:0040DD62                 sub     eax, edx
```

Is the significant code. `EDX:EAX` is the sign-extended version of `SI`, so `EDX` is either 0 or -1. The `xor` either leaves `eax` untouched or inverts it, the `sub` leaves it untouched or adds one and so on in total:

```
if (si < 0) {
    eax = ~si;
    eax += 1;
    eax &= 0x7;
    eax = ~eax;
    eax += 1;
} else {
    eax = si & 0x7;
}
```

The first branch can still be simplified, but I leave that to you...

---

**update**

That the branches only differ for `si<0` already gives a hint at what is happening. The sequence `eax = ~si; eax += 1;` can be understood as the [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so inserting our knowledge of this complement we get

```
if (si < 0) {
    eax = -1 * si;
    eax &= 0x7;
    eax *= -1;
} else {
    eax = si & 0x7;
}
```

or in short

```
eax = (abs(si) & 0x7) * sign(si);
```

Or with the signed modulus operator

```
al = si % 8;
```

Comment: haha if can, can you please simplify it under it, I have no clue whats going on to be honest I would appreciate it, if it doesn't take too much of your time. Doubt a branch was even used here could it be the source code to abs function itself?

Comment: So does that mean it actually is `modulus` and not `&` getting used here?

Comment: @user3435580 sorry I didn't even see that. Yes, it is infact a modulus. `al = si % 8` using the signed `modulus` operator.

Comment: so that 0x1007 is a bitwise mask or something? never seen one like that before. What do you think it originally was as clean as it could be? `NewShip = abs(frequency) & 7);` seems to give the same exact results but then again it's based on what you say what hex-rays decompiled wrong.

Comment: @user3435580 sry, I was confused for a moment (with the 0x1007 mask). Should be correct now.

Comment: Modulus 8 makes sense in a way since the Ships could actually hit 8 possible ships but then again it shouldn't really be possible to hit the 8th value well 9th ship since that ship means you are not playing and why go into a frequency in this game when you are not playing doesn't make sense. You say signed modulus seems like the same operator you mean `% -8`?

Comment: @user3435580 with signed modulus I mean, that `si % 8` preserves the sign of `si`. (fairly likely as the standard c and c++ operators `%` preserve the sign since c99 and c++11)

Comment: ah so the `SI` is negative and the modulus will never actually evaluate to 8?

Comment: @user3435580 values in `al` are in principle -7,-6,...,6,7. Of course it is possible that `si` is always positive, in which case only 0 through 7 can be reached.

Comment: So I can't fix it, since I don't have access to `SI` in the C code and have to keep using `abs(val) & 7` not that I want to have access to it anyways I want it to be clean code for the most part. Also in my answer I found other places that use abs look similar even without the `& 7`. I'll actually test this feature inside the game and find out the true answer was it a `% 7` or a  `& 7` and let you know haha Thanks for the help man

Comment: It's neither :( `& 7 vs % 7` with value `5555` `MOD=4 AND=3` inside the game I was ship `3` so AND was right so far then also tested `9999` should be ship `0` but it gave me `AND=7 MOD=3` I was thinking maybe 7 should of overflowed or something. I'll try it again.

Comment: Okay I can't test all 9999 possibilities in the game would take forever. But it seems only the last freq 9999 I assume breaks the rules which is probably somewhere else in the code. http://pastebin.com/J6dEJMHX

Comment: Okay false alarm you can't be on freq 9999 it already gets reverted back to 0 it's reserved for spectators. Thanks all is known now. Even though it's `SI % 8` it's really `Ship And 7` `Abs` is most likely not needed at all but used as a sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, the decompiler I used IDA-PRO seems to generate these Shift right 32's `>> 32` all over the place and in all cases where I see this a `abs()` function is used it just seems like a useless wrapper for Absolute number Function.

Some examples I found.

```
//1
((((unsigned long)i >> 32) ^ abs(i)) - ((unsigned long)i >> 32))
//2
(((unsigned long)encryption->field_25E >> 32) ^ abs(encryption->field_25E)) - ((unsigned long)encryption->field_25E >> 32);
//3
((((unsigned long)i >> 32) ^ abs(i)) - ((unsigned long)i >> 32))
//4
(((unsigned long)(v104->field_A8 + 1) >> 32) ^ abs(*((unsigned char*)&(v104->field_A8)) + 1) & 7) - ((unsigned long)(v104->field_A8 + 1) >> 32);
//5
(((unsigned long)v11 >> 32) ^ abs(v11)) - ((unsigned long)v11 >> 32);
//6
(((unsigned long)v4->field_262 >> 32) ^ abs(v4->field_262)) - ((unsigned long)v4->field_262 >> 32)
//7
(((unsigned long)v18 >> 32) ^ abs(v18)) - ((unsigned long)v18 >> 32);
//8 (not refactored yet).
((((unsigned long)*(unsigned int *)(v1 + 610) >> 32) ^ abs(*(unsigned int *)(v1 + 610))) - ((unsigned long)*(unsigned int *)(v1 + 610) >> 32)
```

You may also see these `>> 32`'s in 1 more place which I already know is just optimized division from researching and it looks much more different.

Something crazy like this (I fixed this with my regular expression tool)

```
(signed int)((unsigned int)v130 + ((unsigned long)(18446744071705233545i64 * (signed int)v130) >> 32)) >> 5;

//Originally it looked something like this
LODWORD(v202) = (signed int)((_DWORD)v202 + (0xFFFFFFFF88888889ui64 * (signed int)v202 >> 32)) >> 5;

//Or without the hexadecimal values
LODWORD(v202) = (signed int)((_DWORD)v202 + ((unsigned __int64)(18446744071705233545i64 * (signed int)v202) >> 32)) >> 5;

//You will see it getting used like this
(signed int)(((unsigned int)v202 >> 31) + v202)

But what it really means is
v202 / 60
```

The equations used to convert it back to `/ 60` is talked about on http://www.hexblog.com/?p=17